# Slicing strings of a sentence with a scale

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, slice

So I need to create 3 functions for this assignment.
The first should do the following

> numCol(): When dealing with plain text (and data written in plain text), it can be helpful to have a “scale” that indicates the columns in which characters appear. We create a scale using two lines (or “rows”). In the second row, we print 1234567890 repeatedly. In the ﬁrst row (i.e., the line above the second row), we write the “tens” digits above the zeros in the second row as shown in the listing below. This function takes one argument, an integer, and prints a scale the length of your quote. It doesn't return anything.

The second should

> docQuote(): Takes three arguments: 1) the quote as a string, 2) the slice start value, and 3) the slice end value. It returns the doctored string.

The third should

> main(): Takes no arguments and returns nothing. Prompts user for original quote and number
>   of slices needed. Then in a for-loop, calls numCol() in such a way that the scale is the length of the quote, prompts the user for the start and end slice values (recall that the end value isn’t included in the slice), and then calls docQuote(). Finally, it prints the ﬁnal doctored quote.

If the program is correct its output should look as follows:

```
1.  Enter quote: Money is the root of all evil.
2.  Enter the number of slices needed: 2
3.  1 2
4.  012345678901234567890123456789
5.  Money is the root of all evil.
6.  Start and end for slicing separated by a comma: 8, 20
7.  1
8.  012345678901234567
9.  Money is all evil.
10. Start and end for slicing separated by a comma: 12, 17
11. -> Money is all.
```

What I have so far: (Will update if I figure something out)

```
def numCol(x):
    col=[]
    for i in range(1,(round(n)//10)+1):
        col.append(str(i))
    print("         ","         ".join(col),end="")


def docQuote(x,y,z):
   return

def main():
   x=input("Enter quote: ")
   y=int(input("Enter the number of slices needed: "))
   numCol(len(x)-1)
   print(x)

main()
```

Comment: ... and what is your question?

Comment: So what exactly isn't working right about your code?

Comment: According to the instructions, the scale starts with a 1. This doesn't match the sample output.

Comment: @HughBothwell The question appears to be "Will you do my assignment for me?" :/

Comment: Can you provide any details as to where/how your program is incorrect (i.e. where the output goes awry)?

Comment: @HughBothwell Mostly how would I go about setting up the numCol function.

Comment: @MarkThomas I figured it would be better to include all of the info as to make it easier to understand.

Comment: @ScottHunter I'm more in the process of figuring out how to write each part(mostly numCol()) because the instructions say to call to that first(in main).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok: you have to define a function called `numCol` which takes one integer argument:

```
def numCol(n):
```

then you have to print a line consisting of `n` characters, where every tenth character is an incrementing integer and every other character is a space.

```
    chars = []
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        if i % 10:
            chars.append(" ")
        else:
            chars.append(str((i % 100) // 10))
    print(''.join(chars))
```

and finally a row consisting of 'n' chars, being 1234567890 repeating:

```
    chars = []
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        chars.append(str(i % 10))
    print(''.join(chars))
```

which then runs as

```
>>> numCol(65)
         1         2         3         4         5         6     
12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345
```

---

**Edit**:

In response to @AdamSmith:

Let's see some actual numbers:

```
from textwrap import dedent
from timeit import Timer

test_statements = [
    (
        "n = 65",
        """
        # as a for-loop
        chars = []
        for i in xrange(1, n+1):
            if i % 10:
                chars.append(" ")
            else:
                chars.append(str((i % 100) // 10))
        """
    ),
    (
        "n = 65",
        """
        # as a list comprehension
        chars = [" " if i%10 else str((i%100)//10) for i in xrange(1,n+1)]
        """        
    ),
    (
        "n = 65",
        """
        # extra cost of list-to-string
        chars = [" " if i%10 else str((i%100)//10) for i in xrange(1,n+1)]
        s = ''.join(chars)
        """        
    ),
    (
        "n = 65",
        """
        # vs cost of generator-to-string
        chars = (" " if i%10 else str((i%100)//10) for i in xrange(1,n+1))
        s = ''.join(chars)
        """        
    ),
    (
        "s = '         1         2         3         4         5         6     '",
        """
        # cost of actually displaying string
        print(s)
        """
    )
]

for setup,run in test_statements:
    res   = Timer(dedent(run), setup)
    times = res.repeat()   # 3 * 1000000 runs
    print("{:7.1f}".format(min(times))   # time of one loop in microseconds
```

on my system (i5-760, Win7 x64, Python 2.7.5 64bit) this gives

```
   15.1   # for-loop -> list of chars
   10.7   # list comprehension -> list of chars
   11.4   # list comprehension -> string
   13.6   # generator expression -> string
  132.1   # print the string
```

Conclusions:

- a list comprehension is 29% faster than a for-loop at building a list of characters
- a generator expression is 19.6% *slower* than a list comprehension at building a list of characters and joining to a string
- it's pretty much **irrelevant**, because actually printing the output takes 9 times longer than generating it with **any** of these methods - by the time you print the string out, using a list comprehension (fastest) is just 2.9% faster than the for-loop (slowest).

---

@user3482104

If you really want to avoid `if ... else`, you can do

```
if stmt:
    do_a()
if not stmt:    # same effect as 'else:'
    do_b()
```

but be aware that this has to evaluate `stmt` twice where `else` only evaluates it once.

Also, because both loops are iterating over the same range (same start/end values), you can combine the loops:

```
def numCol(n):
    firstline  = []
    secondline = []

    for i in range(1, n+1):
        i %= 100
        tens, ones = i // 10, i % 10
        if ones:        # ones != 0
            firstline.append(" ")
        if not ones:    # ones == 0    # <= 'else:'
            firstline.append(str(tens))
        secondline.append(str(ones))

    print(''.join(firstline))
    print(''.join(secondline))
```

Comment: `chars` can be a list comp and run faster. `chars = [" " if i%10 else str((i%100)//10) for i in range(1,n+1)]` You can even just make it a string (as it ought to be anyhow) by calling `''.join` directly on the list comp when you assign it to `chars`.

Comment: Could probably run the `1234567890` row cheaper too. `nums = "1234567890"; for i in range(n): print(nums[i%10])`

Comment: For the first loop where it increases by 1 for each segment(0123456789) is there anything else you could use besides the "else" because I haven't learned about that in class(even though I understand it) and we are supposed to use what we have learned. Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: Alright, back again. I have updated what I changed in the code but now I am having problems figuring out how to slice the quote in to x amount of pieces starting from x,y

Comment: @user3482104: use string slicing: `"abcde"[1:4] == "bcd"`